# How to navigate to tab + send(NFC) page in windows phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app and i need to navigate to tab + send(NFC) page.How can i achieve this?
I haven't find any ConnectionSettingsTask for this.

Answer (score 2):

- ConnectionSettingsTask, In the menu `ConnectionSettingsType`, it includes the member of WiFi, Bluetooth, Cellular, AirplaneMode, but `NFC`
- Launchers & Choosers. This is all of the [Launchers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769550%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and [Choosers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769543%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for Windows Phone 8 on the official documentation. You will find no Launcher and Chooser can navigate to `tab + Send` `NFC` page.

So it not support in Windows Phone 8, but maybe in the next coming version.